# Is problem solving a inborn skill or a skill which takes lots of hard work and lots of paper?

Tags: soft-question

I asked this because I find myself in situations which trouble me deeply.

I solve a deep interesting problem, I learn a new concept, its good but a single question which I'm not able to do, leaves me depressed, sometimes I can't just understand whether I CAN or CANNOT apply a concept to solve a problem , even though I may have practiced on it.

Seeing solutions to some problems I'm like "Hey I knew this concept, but why didn't I apply it, don't I have that much common sense to apply a concept which I have learned :-

( ". So I just wanted to know, won't I ever get any more good, and seeing all the smaller kids doing these problems makes me kind of even more sad about myself, so I wanted to ask you guys, is it a inborn skill ?

I just feel like it is so. Please help

Comment: It most definitely is not an inborn skill but takes hard work and a lot of time.